# HDF5 library segfault (mismatching headers)

Tags: c++, hdf5, flann

I installed the flann and libhdf5-serial-dev c++ library on ubuntu. After that, I compiled the flann_example.cpp file without problems. However, when I launched the executable I got the following error message :

> Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error***
>   The HDF5 header files used to compile this application do not match
>   the version used by the HDF5 library to which this application is linked.
>   Data corruption or segmentation faults may occur if the application continues.
>   This can happen when an application was compiled by one version of HDF5 but
>   linked with a different version of static or shared HDF5 library.
>   You should recompile the application or check your shared library related
>   settings such as 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'.
>   You can, at your own risk, disable this warning by setting the environment
>   variable 'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' to a value of '1'.
>   Setting it to 2 or higher will suppress the warning messages totally.
>   Headers are 1.8.16, library is 1.8.7
>   Bye...
>   Abandon (core dumped)

I used the following expression to suppress this warning :

```
 cmake -HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=1 -H. -Bbuild
```

But I still have this message. I looked for the optional flag HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK with ccmake to check if it's setting to 1. But I couldn't see this flag.
Someone could help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can, at your own risk, disable this warning by setting the environment variable 'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' to a value of '1'.

`HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK` is an environment variable, not a compiler `#define` or CMake variable. Set it within your shell:

```
export HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=1
path/to/flann_example
```

or

```
HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=1 path/to/flann_example
```

However, you're probably much better off fixing the root problem (the library mismatch). On Ubuntu, if you always install the Ubuntu-packaged versions of libraries (via `apt`, `aptitude`, Synaptic...) instead of installing libraries yourself, this should ensure that all library versions are compatible.

Comment: Thx, I will try that. To get the HDF library I do the following instruction : sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev  and I got this message.

Comment: @axel - Where are you getting flann from?

Comment: @axel - Are you using the source distribution, or the binary? Which version of Ubuntu are you running? If you're building from source against an Ubuntu-provided .deb, you shouldn't encounter this error.